# ApiError-Binance api

Tags: python, websocket, binance, binance-api-client

I am using the API from binance to create test order but it is showing me this error:

[image: code of order request]

[image: response from the above code]

When I log out from the desktop app and log in again it works, but after the first response it shows the above error. Again I have to log out and log in. As you can iamgine it is really painful.

The code :

```
order = client.create_test_order(symbol='BTCBUSD',type='MARKET', side ='BUY',quantity=0.005)
print(order)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\182_Suhel\PycharmProjects\learn_crypto\main.py", line 69, in <module>
    order = client.create_test_order(symbol='BTCBUSD',type='MARKET', side ='BUY',quantity=0.005)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\182_Suhel\PycharmProjects\learn_crypto\venv\Lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1825, in create_test_order
    return self._post('order/test', True, data=params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\182_Suhel\PycharmProjects\learn_crypto\venv\Lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 417, in _post
    return self._request_api('post', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\182_Suhel\PycharmProjects\learn_crypto\venv\Lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 377, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\182_Suhel\PycharmProjects\learn_crypto\venv\Lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 358, in _request
    return self._handle_response(self.response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\182_Suhel\PycharmProjects\learn_crypto\venv\Lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 367, in _handle_response
    raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.
```

I tried creating other API from the web site in the hope it will fix the problem but it didn't.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Post your code, and the full error trace message, as text.

Comment: Looks like you can't use the same credentials to log in to the API and the desktop app at the same time.  You have to pick one or the other.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method `create_test_order`, you should only call the API by testnet API key; Using prod API key will return this error.